# Crear campo en un relación de muchos a muchos sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, sequelize.js

estoy usando ORMsequelize en nodejs y estoy haciendo una relación de muchos a muchos entre dos tablas evidentemente esto lo que hace es crear una tabla intermedia.

```
//Devices - Executables
devices.belongsToMany(executables, { through: 'devices_has_executables' });
executables.belongsToMany(devices, { through: 'devices_has_executables' });
```

pero mi duda en este caso es que en esta tablla creada llamada "devices_has_executables" quiero crear un campo nuevo es eso posible desde esta misma sentencía o debo crear el modelo "devices_has_executables"

Comment: Entiendo que hay un parametro options segun la documentación pero nos e usarlo para crear un compo

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que definir el modelo que se usara para la relación, allí pones el nuevo campo.

```
const Devices_has_executables = sequelize.define("devices_has_executables",{
 nueva_columna: DataTypes.INTEGER
},{timestamps: true});
devices.belongsToMany(executables, { through: Devices_has_executables  });
executables.belongsToMany(devices, { through: Devices_has_executables  });
```

Suerte, no olvides importar DataTypes from sequelize si no lo tienes ya

```
const DataTypes = require('sequelize/lib/data-types');
```

Comment: Sip ya lo habia echo asi tal cual solo que to tengo separado la creación de las tablas del modelo donde se ejecutan als funciones